# Change password button enabling without the password check confirmation on newpassword with comfirmpassword?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, frontend

`Ng-disable` isn't applying for `changepassword` check with new password .Even though proper directive is written to compare and check the validiaty ?

Passwrod Matching is not working.The code is written only to enable the change password  on `newpassword` and `confrimpassword` being similar. But after the new password placeholder is filled the Change password Button is being enabled.

```
HTMl
<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputPassword" class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
<div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-right-1 input-group">
<input type="{{inputType}}" class="form-control" id="pw2" placeholder="Re enter the password" name="pw2" ng-model="forgotPwdkeys.confirmPassword" ng-required="" pw-check="pw1">
<span class="input-group-addon">
<span class="{{showHideClass}}" ng-click="showConfirmPassword()" style="cursor:pointer"></span>
</span>
</div>
<div class="msg-block passwordMask" ng-show="forgotpwdForm.$error"> <span class="msg-error" ng-show="forgotpwdForm.pw2.$error.pwmatch">Passwords don't match.</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-12" style="text-align:center">
<button class="btn btn-raised btn-primary" ng-disabled="forgotpwdForm.$pristine || forgotpwdForm.$invalid " ng-click="resetNewPwd();">Change</button>
</div>
</div>
```

```
directive

MainApp.directive('pwCheck', [function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            var firstPassword = '#' + attrs.pwCheck;
            elem.add(firstPassword).on('keyup', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    var v = elem.val() === $(firstPassword).val();
                    console.log(v);
                    console.log('pwmatch')
                    ctrl.$setValidity('pwmatch', v);
                });
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

`

Passwords don't match.